# Php passing variable names

Tags: php

Can someone please explain to me what this piece of php code means.

```
echo "<a href='product.php?product_id".$product_id."'>
```

Is it saying that the link is taken from a variable from the product.php page and its named $product_id?

Comment: This is explained on the first page of any PHP text. There's no point in asking about it in a forum.

Comment: This is basic knowledge of PHP programming. You should probably study some more, go through some PHP tutorials etc. Just to get you started though, here is an explanation: 
This code prints [HTML link tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) that redirects to file 'product.php' which is PHP script that should be able to process GET request that contains variable 'product_id' with variable value (this value is defined in this script and is taken from variable `$product_id`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a GET parameter in the URL (it's also wrong btw). Say `$product_id`  = 1.

```
echo "<a href='product.php?product_id".$product_id."'>
```

This would be "product.php?product_id1"

```
echo "<a href='product.php?product_id=".$product_id."'>
```

This would be "product.php?product_id=1", which would would handle by using

```
$_GET["product_id"]; //yields 1
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you.  But one more question, what is with the ? between product.php ad product_id=  ??? Is this just saying that the variable product_id can be found from the product.php page?

Comment: The question mark means this is the start of URL parameters, it's not default to the URL

Answer (score 0):

Ths snippet outputs an HTML `<a>` tag. The `$product_id` is a variable, and `echo` is the command to output a string.
But I'd recommend to follow some basic Tutorials about HTML and PHP, as these are some of the most basic things.